# Pandas: median if len greater than 4 for pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I'm trying to have NS display if the number of data points for each industry per quarter is less then 4.

Here is my data source:

```
print df

                        IndustryGroup  Year_  Quarter  TotalRaisedUSD
                            Healthcare  2014_        1        79.30000
                     Consumer Services  2014_        1       111.25000
                Information Technology  2014_        1       232.00000
                            Healthcare  2014_        1       113.90000
                            Healthcare  2014_        1       121.11000
                            Healthcare  2014_        1       108.76000
                            Healthcare  2014_        1        58.64000
                            Healthcare  2014_        1       120.07000
                            Healthcare  2014_        1        81.76000
                            Healthcare  2014_        1        28.40000
                            Healthcare  2014_        1        76.63000
                            Healthcare  2014_        1        74.96217
                            Healthcare  2014_        1        57.86000
                            Healthcare  2014_        1       220.23000
                                ...     ...         ...       ...
                            Healthcare  2014_        4       109.70000
                     Consumer Services  2014_        4       358.50000
                            Healthcare  2014_        4       115.00000
                Information Technology  2014_        4       168.05000
       Business and Financial Services  2014_        4       100.66000
                            Healthcare  2014_        4        72.09000
                            Healthcare  2014_        4       129.67000
                            Healthcare  2014_        4       151.00000
                            Healthcare  2014_        4       123.28000
                            Healthcare  2014_        4       153.85000
       Business and Financial Services  2014_        4        47.41000
                            Healthcare  2014_        4        35.34000
                            Healthcare  2014_        4       206.50000
                            Healthcare  2014_        4        31.00000
                            Healthcare  2014_        4        68.09000
                            Healthcare  2014_        4       122.02000
       Business and Financial Services  2014_        4       193.22000
                Information Technology  2014_        4       254.34000
                Information Technology  2014_        4       196.50000


df1=pd.pivot_table(df,values='TotalRaisedUSD',index='IndustryGroup',columns=['Year_','Quarter'], np.median)
```

I need the same df1 output but displaying "NS" if the count of TotalRaisedUSD is less than 4 (For example Information Technology 2014_ 4 should display NS)

```
  [108 rows x 4 columns]
  Year_                             2014_                        
  Quarter                               1        2      3       4
  IndustryGroup                                                  
  Business and Financial Services   49.73   71.275  38.00  100.66
  Consumer Services                111.25  165.600    NaN  358.50
  Healthcare                        87.10   82.335  84.53  118.51
  Industrial Goods and Materials      NaN  144.490    NaN     NaN
  Information Technology            82.13   68.000  55.93  196.50
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Comment: It's hard to tell without an example, but you could try `groupby` (along [these lines](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19385591/5276797) for instance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `groupby` and `transform` to accomplish this:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['IndustryGroup','Year'])

logic= lambda x: 'NS' if x.count() < 4 else '' 

transformed = grouped.transform(logic)
```

I believe something like this should work.

You can read about it here:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html