# How do I find the frequency of each pairing of a street and its intersection in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I would like to find the frequency of the pairing of each street name + cross name that appears in the data using pandas. For instance, here is a sample of the data:

```
Street Name        Cross Streets
Massachusetts Ave  Rindge Ave
Massachusetts Ave  NaN
Franklin Street    Sidney Street
Massachusetts Ave  Rindge Ave
```

How do I count the frequency of each pairing of street name and cross name and how can I also find the count of streets with no pairings (for instance the one with NaN)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

Load library and import your data

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", delimiter=",", na_values="NaN")    
In [3]: df
Out[3]:
        Street Name   Cross Street
0  Massachusetts Ave     Rindge Ave
1  Massachusetts Ave            NaN
2    Franklin Street  Sidney Street
3  Massachusetts Ave     Rindge Ave
```

> "count the frequency of each pairing of street name and cross name"

... by grouping the street name and cross street and counting how many in each group

```
In [4]: df.groupby(['Street Name', 'Cross Street']).size()
Out[4]:
Street Name        Cross Street
Franklin Street    Sidney Street    1
Massachusetts Ave  Rindge Ave       2
dtype: int64
```

> "find the count of streets with no pairings (for instance the one with NaN)"

... by grouping the street name and counting how many NaN is in cross street

```
In [5]: df.groupby("Street Name").agg(lambda x: x["Cross Street"].isnull().sum())
Out[5]:
                  Cross Street
Street Name
Franklin Street               0
Massachusetts Ave             1
```

Comment: Thanks for this! What's the difference between size() and count() though in pandas?

Comment: @dancemc15 huh -- to be honest, I'm not too sure (I was referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384532/how-to-count-number-of-rows-in-a-group-in-pandas-group-by-object when I was answering the question)

Comment: @dancemc15 More googling: `count` computes count of group, excluding missing values (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) and `size` computes group sizes (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html); .... because there is NaN in the data, using count() would not work

Comment: Okay, understood.