# How can I remove rows where frequency of the value is less than 5? Python, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with lots of rows.  Sometimes are values are one ofs and not very useful for my purpose.

How can I remove all the rows from where columns 2 and 3's value doesn't appear more than 5 times?

df input

```
 Col1     Col2     Col3       Col4
 1        apple    tomato     banana
 1        apple    potato     banana
 1        apple    tomato     banana
 1        apple    tomato     banana
 1        apple    tomato     banana
 1        apple    tomato     banana
 1        grape    tomato     banana
 1        pear     tomato     banana
 1        lemon    tomato     banana
```

output

```
 Col1     Col2     Col3       Col4
 1        apple    tomato     banana
 1        apple    tomato     banana
 1        apple    tomato     banana
 1        apple    tomato     banana
 1        apple    tomato     banana
```

Comment: Check this very useful answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384532/how-to-count-number-of-rows-in-a-group-in-pandas-group-by-object

Comment: Are you checking based on global counts, or column wise counts? Does it matter even? Is it possible that `apple` also appears in Col3, besides Col2?

Comment: @coldspeed column wise count.   counts are restricted to the column so it doesn't if apple appears in a different column, it should be based on col2's count

Comment: What if it is 'potato` in the first value of `Col3`? What should be the desired output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Global Counts**
Use `stack` + `value_counts` + `replace` -

```
v = df[['Col2', 'Col3']]
df[v.replace(v.stack().value_counts()).gt(5).all(1)]

   Col1   Col2    Col3    Col4
0     1  apple  tomato  banana
2     1  apple  tomato  banana
3     1  apple  tomato  banana
4     1  apple  tomato  banana
5     1  apple  tomato  banana
```

---

(Update)
**Columnwise Counts**

Call `apply` with `pd.Series.value_counts` on your columns of interest, and filter in the same manner as before -

```
v = df[['Col2', 'Col3']]
df[v.replace(v.apply(pd.Series.value_counts)).gt(5).all(1)]

   Col1   Col2    Col3    Col4
0     1  apple  tomato  banana
2     1  apple  tomato  banana
3     1  apple  tomato  banana
4     1  apple  tomato  banana
5     1  apple  tomato  banana
```

*Details*
Use `value_counts` to count values in your dataframe -

```
c = v.apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
c

        Col2  Col3
apple    6.0   NaN
grape    1.0   NaN
lemon    1.0   NaN
pear     1.0   NaN
potato   NaN   1.0
tomato   NaN   8.0
```

Call `replace`, to replace values in the DataFrame with their counts -

```
i = v.replace(c)
i

   Col2  Col3
0     6     8
1     6     1
2     6     8
3     6     8
4     6     8
5     6     8
6     1     8
7     1     8
8     1     8
```

From that point,

```
m = i.gt(5).all(1)

0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6    False
7    False
8    False
dtype: bool
```

Use the mask to index `df`.

Comment: This will also filter out the Col4 which we dont want to. As well as this counts all the values - not in separate columns. So we can have problems with same values in different columns.

Comment: Just change one "tomato" to "apple" in Col3 and there is a problem. Here we need column-wise counting.

Comment: @AlexeyTrofimov That's your interpretation. My interpretation is that the counts are global, based on my understanding of the question. We'll wait for OP to clarify before we discuss any further ;)

Comment: counts are based on each row @AlexeyTrofimov I am trying to clean low frequency values in this dataset

Comment: @aidenrosenblatt Each _row_? Okay, which of these answers have worked for you thus far? There are multiple interpretations to your question, so I'm trying to understand which one it is you need.

Comment: I also dont get the _each row_ part :)

Comment: this solution looks at global counts i need column counts

Answer (score 5):

Easy way with transform

```
counts_col2 = df.groupby("Col2")["Col2"].transform(len)
counts_col3 = df.groupby("Col3")["Col3"].transform(len)

mask = (counts_col2 > 5) & (counts_col3 > 5)

df[mask]
```

output:

```
   Col1   Col2    Col3    Col4
0     1  apple  tomato  banana
2     1  apple  tomato  banana
3     1  apple  tomato  banana
4     1  apple  tomato  banana
5     1  apple  tomato  banana
```

Comment: What about Col4? What if there are 10 columns? Will you call groupby on each one?

Comment: In this paticular Q we focus only on Col2 and Col3 as far as i can see.

Comment: The second part of my question still applies. What if there are 10 other columns?

Comment: We can easily loop through them, store counts in list, make a mask.

Comment: If you're using `groupby`, you can use `.filter` instead of `tranform`: 
`df.groupby("Col2").filter(lambda grp: len(grp) > 3)`

Comment: @Alexey Trofimov can you explain df.groupby("Col2")["Col2"].transform(len) what does this mean

Comment: @ZestyDragon this creates the column with the counts for each value of this column.

Answer (score 1):

To create the example data frame

```
import pandas as pd

text = '''Col1     Col2     Col3       Col4
 1        apple    tomato     banana
 1        apple    potato     banana
 1        apple    tomato     banana
 1        apple    tomato     banana
 1        apple    tomato     banana
 1        apple    tomato     banana
 1        grape    tomato     banana
 1        pear     tomato     banana
 1        lemon    tomato     banana'''

count = 1
data = []
for line in text.split('\n'):
    if count == 1:
        headers = line.split()
    else:
        data.append(line.split())
    count += 1

df = pd.DataFrame(data = data,columns=headers)
```

The value_counts method produces a dict with unique column values as the keys and a count as the value. It is these keys I am assigning to k.

- value_counts returns a Pandas series object but it is like a dict

This list comprehension has a filtering 'if' statement that ignores keys if the value associated with it isn't > 5

In this example, it returns a list with only one value, but it other cases it could be more.

```
Col2_more_than_5 = [k for k in df['Col2'].value_counts().keys() 
if df['Col2'].value_counts()[k] > 5]

Col3_more_than_5 = [k for k in df['Col3'].value_counts().keys() 
if df['Col3'].value_counts()[k] > 5]
```

I now have two lists that contain the string/s that occur > 5 times in each column and now I create a selector that returns rows where both statements are true

```
df[(df['Col2'].isin(Col2_more_than_5)) & (df['Col3'].isin(Col3_more_than_5))]
```

The 'isin' method works if there are more than 1 value in the list

[image]

Comment: what does this code do? df[(df['Col2'] == first[0]) & (df['Col3'] == second[0]) ]

Comment: it uses the value from each of the list comprehensions to filter the columns

Comment: add some description to justify your answer.

Comment: I have modified my answer to something that is clearer and a little more robust if there are more than 1 value greater than 5 I also added more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
v=df.astype(str).sum(1)
df[v.eq(v.value_counts()[v.value_counts()>=5].index.values[0])]
Out[145]: 
   Col1   Col2    Col3    Col4
0     1  apple  tomato  banana
2     1  apple  tomato  banana
3     1  apple  tomato  banana
4     1  apple  tomato  banana
5     1  apple  tomato  banana
```

Comment: Hmm... calling `value_counts` twice seems wasteful. Maybe cache the intermediate result??

Answer (score 1):

Fastest way by @ALollz

```
def agg_size_nosort(df):
    counts_col2 = df.groupby("Col2", sort=False)["Col2"].transform('size')
    counts_col3 = df.groupby("Col3", sort=False)["Col3"].transform('size')
    mask = (counts_col2 > 5) & (counts_col3 > 5)
    return df[mask]
```

Answer (score 0):

One can also use [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) twice.

```
df.groupby("Col2").filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 5) \
  .groupby("Col3").filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 5)
```

The documentation of [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) 
 says

> Return a copy of a DataFrame excluding elements from groups that do
>   not satisfy the boolean criterion specified by func.