# dataframe remove rows with less than 5 duplicate values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

This is how my dataset looks:[dataset sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcO5Q.png)

I am trying to remove player entries that has less than 5 years (5 entries of the same name) from the whole dataset. So in the sample snapshot, A.C. Green rows should be left untouched.

I have tried this line of code from a similar question ([How can I remove rows where frequency of the value is less than 5? Python, Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48513886/how-can-i-remove-rows-where-frequency-of-the-value-is-less-than-5-python-panda)):

```
n = playersData[['Player']]
playersData[n.replace(n.apply(pd.Series.value_counts)).gt(5).all(1)]
```

but the df.shape shows there is no decrease in rows.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. First of all, I suggest you to not paste images of dataframe, look here for [how to make a good pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). Secondly, is this what you're looking for? `playersData.groupby("Player").filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 5)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try:

```
n = playersData[['Player']]
playerData = playersData[n.replace(n.apply(pd.Series.value_counts)).gt(5).all(1)]
```