# python pandas: find the top 3 frequent names

Tags: python, pandas

For the dataframe below,find the top 3 frequent names

```
Index      Name   
1          Jack     
2          Jack
3          Tom  
4          Tom  
5          Lucy  
6          Lily
7          Lily
The result should be 

  Name      Frequency 
  Jack      2
  Tome      2
  Lily      2
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: Group by condition with `groupby`, count values with `value_counts`, take top two with `head`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `groupby` with `apply` and `nlargest`:

```
result_df = df.groupby('Condition')['Name'].apply(lambda grp: grp.value_counts().nlargest(2)).reset_index()
result_df.columns = ['Condition','Name','Frequency']
print(result_df)
```

Result:

```
  Condition  Name  Frequency
0         a  Jack          2
1         a   Tom          2
2         b  Lily          2
3         b  Lucy          1
```

## Update

For edited question, probably following will work:

```
df.groupby('Name').size().nlargest(3).to_frame('Frequency')
```

Result:

```
      Frequency
Name           

Jack          2
Lily          2
Tom           2
```

Comment: Yeah, but I'm unmotivated by questions that change scope... so I'll pass.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
df.groupby(['Condition','Name']).size()
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384532/how-to-count-number-of-rows-in-a-group-in-pandas-group-by-object) explain better.