# how to make countplot in plotly

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

I am new to plotly. I am trying to create a countplot in plotly. I am reading a dataframe and here are my columns and values in the dataframe.

Name    Defect severity

User1   Medium

User1   Medium

User1   High

User2   High

Here's how I would like the final graph to be shown

[image: img]

Can anyone suggest me how to code in Plotly?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with two lines of code, with the help of pandas `groupby` and plotly's `barmode` attribute.

Plotly's bar chart has a specific attribute to control how to show the bars, it's called `barmode`, quoting the API documentation:

> barmode: str (default `'relative'`)
> One of `'group'`, `'overlay'` or `'relative'` In `'relative'` mode,
> bars are stacked above zero for positive values and below zero for
> negative values. In `'overlay'` mode, bars are drawn on top of one
> another. In `'group'` mode, bars are placed beside each other.

See the [bar chart documentation](https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/) for examples.

Now, for your example:

```
# import needed libraries
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# some dummy dataset
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Name": ["User1", "User1", "User1", "User2"],
        "Defect severity": ["Medium", "Medium", "High", "High"],
    }
)
```

You need to group by both `Name` and `Defect severity` columns, and then use the `count` aggregating function (I recommend you take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384532/get-statistics-for-each-group-such-as-count-mean-etc-using-pandas-groupby))

```
df = df.groupby(by=["Name", "Defect severity"]).size().reset_index(name="counts")
```

The data now will look like the following:

|  | Name | Defect severity | counts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | User1 | High | 1 |
| 1 | User1 | Medium | 2 |
| 2 | User2 | High | 1 |

Finally, you can use plotly bar chart:

```
px.bar(data_frame=df, x="Name", y="counts", color="Defect severity", barmode="group")
```

The chart would be:

[image]

There you go! with only two lines of code, you got a nice *grouped* bar chart.

Answer (score 2):

I created almost all what you want. Unfortunately, I did not find a way to set the title in the legend correctly(`annotations` is not good parameter to set a legend title). And to display numbers (1.0,2.0) it is necessary to create an additional column with values (column - `df["Severity numbers"]`).

Code:

```
# import all the necessaries libraries
import pandas as pd
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name":["User1","User1", "User1","User2"],
                   "Defect severity":["Medium","Medium","High","High"],
                   "Severity numbers":[1,1,2,2]})
# Create two additional DataFrames to traces
df1 = df[df["Defect severity"] == "Medium"]
df2 = df[df["Defect severity"] == "High"]
# Create two traces, first "Medium" and second "High"
trace1 = go.Bar(x=df1["Name"], y=df1["Severity numbers"], name="Medium")
trace2 = go.Bar(x=df2["Name"], y=df2["Severity numbers"], name="High")
# Fill out  data with our traces
data = [trace1, trace2]
# Create layout and specify title, legend and so on
layout = go.Layout(title="Severity",
                   xaxis=dict(title="Name"),
                   yaxis=dict(title="Count of defect severity"),
                   legend=dict(x=1.0, y=0.5),
                   # Here annotations need to create legend title
                   annotations=[
                                dict(
                                    x=1.05,
                                    y=0.55,
                                    xref="paper",
                                    yref="paper",
                                    text="      Defect severity",
                                    showarrow=False
                                )],
                   barmode="group")
# Create figure with all prepared data for plot
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
# Create a plot in your Python script directory with name "bar-chart.html"
plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename="bar-chart.html")
```

Output:
[image: Hope it is what you want]

Comment: @prasanna, my answer help you?

Comment: @prasanna, if my answer help you, do not forget check it as an answer. And welcome to Stackverflow!=)

Comment: @Oyisi..Thak you so much..:) the solution worked..:)

Comment: @prasanna, nice to hear that) You can check my solution as answer or upvote - it will can help others with similar problem found this solution more easily. Have a nice day!)

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [
    go.Bar(
        y=coach_sectors['Sectors'].value_counts().to_dense().keys(),
        x=coach_sectors['Sectors'].value_counts(),
        orientation='h',
        text="d",
    )]
layout = go.Layout(
    height=500,
    title='Sector/ Area of Coaches - Combined',
    hovermode='closest',
    xaxis=dict(title='Votes', ticklen=5, zeroline=False, gridwidth=2, domain=[0.1, 1]),
    yaxis=dict(title='', ticklen=5, gridwidth=2),
    showlegend=False
)
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig, filename='Sector/ Area of Coaches - Combined')
```