# How to use sns countplot on plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, seaborn

My aim is to make same thing in plotly:
sns.countplot(x='Survived', data=train, hue='Sex')
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6PPv.png)

Then I wrote this code. But I couldn't print **y** values:

```
df1 = df[df["Survived"] == 0]
df2 = df[df["Survived"] == 1]

fig = go.Figure()

# Create layout and specify title, legend and so on
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    x=df["Sex"],
    y=df2,
    name="Survived",
    marker_color='lightgreen'
))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    x=df["Sex"],
    y=df1,
    name= "Died",
    marker_color="red"
))

fig.update_layout(title_text='Survived/Died passengers by Sex', barmode='group')
#fig.layout.yaxis.type = 'category'
fig.show()
```

By the way, I used the titanic dataset.

Saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467562/how-to-make-countplot-in-plotly) on StackOverflow but didn't help.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The intended graph can be obtained by specifying the Y-axis data counted for each category, and setting a unique value for gender.

```
fig = go.Figure()

# Create layout and specify title, legend and so on
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    x=df2["sex"].unique(),
    y=df2["sex"].value_counts(),
    name="Survived",
    marker_color='lightgreen'
))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    x=df1["sex"].unique(),
    y=df1["sex"].value_counts(),
    name= "Died",
    marker_color="red"
))

fig.update_layout(title_text='Survived/Died passengers by Sex', barmode='group')
fig.update_yaxes(title='Count')
fig.update_xaxes(title='Sex')

fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks this one worked

```
df = train.copy()
df = df.drop(["Pclass","Name","Age","SibSp","Parch","Ticket","Fare","Cabin","Embarked"], axis=1)

df1 = df[df["Survived"] == 0]
df2 = df[df["Survived"] == 1]

fig = go.Figure()

# Create layout and specify title, legend and so on
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    x=df["Sex"],
    y=df2.value_counts(),
    name="Survived",
    marker_color='lightgreen'
))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    x=df["Sex"],
    y=df1.value_counts(),
    name= "Died",
    marker_color="red"
))

fig.update_layout(title_text='Survived/Died passengers by Sex', barmode='group')
#fig.layout.yaxis.type = 'category'
fig.show()
```