# How to count nulls in a group rowwise in pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas

According to this topic `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384532/how-to-count-number-of-rows-per-group-and-other-statistics-in-pandas-group-by` I'd like to add one more stat - count null values (a.k.a. NaN) in DataFrame:

```
tdf = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['indicator', 'v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4'], 
                   data = [['A', '3', pd.np.nan, '4', pd.np.nan ],
                           ['A', '3', '4', '4', pd.np.nan ],
                           ['B', pd.np.nan, pd.np.nan, pd.np.nan, pd.np.nan],
                           ['B', '1', None, pd.np.nan, None ],
                           ['C', '9', '7', '4', '0']])
```

I'd like to use something like this:

`tdf.groupby('indicator').agg({'indicator': ['count']})`

but with the addition of nulls counter to have it in separate column, like:

`tdf.groupby('indicator').agg({'indicator': ['count', 'isnull']})`

Now, I get error: `AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'isnull' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method`

How can I access this `pd.isnull()` function here or use some with its functionality?

Expected output would be:

```
          indicator      nulls
              count      count
indicator          
A                 2          3
B                 2          7
C                 1          0
```

Note that `pd.np.nan` works as `None` in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and check all missing values with count by `sum` and then aggregate `count` with `sum`:

```
df = tdf.set_index('indicator').isnull().sum(axis=1).groupby(level=0).agg(['count','sum'])
print (df)
           count  sum
indicator            
A              2    3
B              2    7
C              1    0
```

**Detail**:

```
print (tdf.set_index('indicator').isnull().sum(axis=1))
indicator
A    2
A    1
B    4
B    3
C    0
dtype: int64
```

Another solution is use function with [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
def func(x):
    a = len(x)
    b = x.isnull().values.sum()
    return pd.Series([a,b],index=['indicator count','nulls count'])

df = tdf.set_index('indicator').groupby('indicator').apply(func)
print (df)
           indicator count  nulls count
indicator                              
A                        2            3
B                        2            7
C                        1            0
```

Comment: I like your first solution - it's twice shorter than mine.

Answer (score 0):

I've found almost satisfying answer myself: (cons: bit too complicated). In R for example I'd use `RowSums` on `is.na(df)` matrix. It's quite this way but more coding unfortunately.

```
def count_nulls_rowwise_by_group(tdf, group):
    cdf = pd.concat([tdf[group], pd.isnull(tdf).sum(axis=1).rename('nulls')], axis=1)
    return cdf.groupby(group).agg({group: 'count', 'nulls': 'sum'}).rename(index=str, columns={group: 'count'})
```

`count_nulls_rowwise_by_group(tdf)`

gives:

```
Out[387]: 
           count  nulls
indicator              
A              2      3
B              2      7
C              1      0
```