# Probability of re occurring an event

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below:

```
ItemNumber ItemName 
264         400
264         420
264         400
264         420
264         420
513         508
513         508
513         400
513         400
513         126
513         126
```

here i would like to see frequency of particular `ItemName`. and probability of reoccurring an `ItemName` with respect to `ItemNumber`.

I have tried using `groupby` function but I'm not getting the desired format using approach below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ByItemName = df.groupby(['ItemName'])
```

My desired output:

```
ItemNumber ItemName ItemNameFrequency
264        400      2
264        420      3
513        508      2
513        400      2
513        126      2
```

Comment: `df.groupby(['ItemNumber ', 'ItemName']).size()`?

Comment: Check second answer - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32801170/2901002)

Comment: @DirtyBit please don't make such unsubstantial edits to the posts as the one here, you are only creating more noise without any improvement.

Comment: @SzymonMaszke It wasn't an unsubstantial edit, I was halfway through and I guess you approved it. anyway no worries! (Y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ItemNumber' : ['264', '264', '264', '264','264','513','513','513','513', '513','513'], 'ItemName' : ['400','420','400','420','420','508','508','400','400', '126','126']})
df = df.groupby(['ItemNumber', 'ItemName']).size().reset_index(name = 'ItemNameFrequency')
print(df)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
  ItemNumber ItemName  ItemNameFrequency
0        264      400                  2
1        264      420                  3
2        513      126                  2
3        513      400                  2
4        513      508                  2
```

Comment: @jezrael Indeed, omitted the series part, thank you!