# How to view elements in a Group of a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a DataFrame of 2 columns,

Index - which are grouped code numbers

frequency - which is the no of elements in that group.

I want to find the elements in that group. How do I do it?

I tried using `MY_DF = DF_1.get_group('12345678')` . It gives me

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'get_group'

Expected output is rows and columns of elements having code no 12345678

Comment: Please provide the sample of your dataset, expected output and what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering on columns can be done with:

```
my_df = df[column_name=='12345678']
```

Consider to read and learn pandas basics: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html

Answer (score 0):

Your questions a bit vague, it would be nice if you can provide a sample df / some code you tried.

From your question is looks like you are looking for something like:

`MY_DF.groupby(['Index', 'frequency']).size()`

You could also create a dataframe from it using:

`MY_DF.groupby(['Index', 'frequency]).size().reset_index(name='counts')`

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384532/get-statistics-for-each-group-such-as-count-mean-etc-using-pandas-groupby) for more information.