# Count common occurrence of elements in Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe of the form :

```
element1  |  element2  |  element3
  'dog'        'cat'         'pig'
  'dog'        'weasel'      'parrot'
  'dog'        'cat'         'pig'
  'cat'        'dog'         'pig'
  'buffalo'    'cow'         'snake'
```

where all elements are strings. How can I count the number of occurrences of each triplet (from every row) and set it as an additional column ? The desired result should be:

```
element1  |  element2  |  element3   |  count  |
  'dog'        'cat'         'pig'         2
  'dog'        'weasel'      'parrot'      1
  'cat'        'dog'         'pig'         1
  'buffalo'    'cow'         'snake'       1
```

where duplicate rows are also removed.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32801170/2901002)

Comment: @jezrael  df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']].groupby(['col1', 'col2']).agg(['count']) ? This? I will try it now.

Comment: Ok, so use `df1 = df.groupby(['element1','element2','element3']).size().reset_index(name='count')`

Comment: oh, ok, that works. Thanks. :)