# How to count values in dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For the dataframe as below

```
     animal    direction

0    monkey    north
1    frog      north
2    monkey    east
3    zebra     west
....
```

I would like to count the number of animals presented in this dataframe to have the below dataframe

```
     animal     count

0    monkey     3
1    frog       9
2    zebra      4
3    elephant   11
....
```

How can I achieve this? I tried value_counts(), and groupby but with my knowledge I couldn't quite achieve what I wanted... 
Thank you for help.

Comment: or this [get-statistics-for-each-group-such-as-count-mean-etc-using-pandas-groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384532/get-statistics-for-each-group-such-as-count-mean-etc-using-pandas-groupby)

Comment: What's wrong with `.value_counts()`?

Comment: Thank you, I found the solution from sjd's link!

Comment: @jorijnsmit After doing the ```.value_counts()``` and performing ```reset_index()``` to have the index, it was weird. It gave me a dummie column name "index" and I was not able to change the name of that. When I tried to change the name, it'll lose the index I assigned by ```reset_index()```...

Comment: Please answer your own question if you have found a solution.

Comment: @jorijnsmit oh, sorry didn't know there was such a thing.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

df.groupby(['col1']).size().reset_index(name='counts')

This method worked beautifully. Thank you.