# frequency of words in excel sheet using Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, series

I'm trying to count the frequency of each word in an excel sheet which is structured as bellow,

[image]

and expecting the output to be like this

[image]

````
```f=pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', header=None)
f.columns = ["id","information"]
f['count']=1
f.groupby(['id']).count()
f.to_excel('output.xlsx')```
````

Comment: check second answer.

Comment: which answer please? jezrael

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32801170/2901002

Comment: sir i want find the frequency of each word means, if there is 5 (goes) it should print 5 or if there is 5 (goes) print in the first (goes) 5? any solution