# Python itertools groupby with aggregate

Tags: python, pandas, python-itertools

I am trying to group on a column based on the sequence it appears (timestamp) and simultaneously finding aggregate (mean) on the other variables within the small group. I can successfully group it but unable to aggregate

Here is my sample input:

```
Date        T/F X1
12/02/19    T   10
12/02/19    T   20
12/02/19    F   15
12/02/19    T   12
12/03/19    F   10
12/03/19    F   20
12/03/19    T   30
12/04/19    T   40
```

Expected O/P

```
Date        T/F X1  Count
12/02/19    T   15  2
12/02/19    F   15  1
12/02/19    T   12  1
12/03/19    F   15  2
12/03/19    T   35  2
```

Here is the code I am using, which groups and give me the count for each group, how do I get the avg of X1 as well, within that group

```
import itertools 
for (key,group) in itertools.groupby(df['T/F']): 
    print (key, len(list(group)))
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get statistics for each group (such as count, mean, etc) using pandas GroupBy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384532/get-statistics-for-each-group-such-as-count-mean-etc-using-pandas-groupby)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
df1 = df.assign(Count=np.nan).\
groupby(df['T/F'].ne(df['T/F'].shift()).cumsum(), as_index=False).\
agg({'Date': 'first', 'T/F': 'first', 'X1': 'mean', 'Count': 'size'})

print(df1)
```

Output:

```
       Date T/F  X1  Count
0  12/02/19   T  15      2
1  12/02/19   F  15      1
2  12/02/19   T  12      1
3  12/03/19   F  15      2
4  12/03/19   T  35      2
```