# Average value in field Advanced pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a question on advanced pandas. Currently, my dataframe’s columns are celebrities, date (YYYY-MM-DD), and No. of followers. For each date,  it will show the new no. of followers.

[image: sample data]

However, I would like to calculate the average no. of new followers from the starting date, 2020/1/1 to 2020/4/1 for each celebrity in a table format with only the celebrity and no. Of followers in the column.

[image: what I want to look like]

How do I write a python code on this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try: `df.groupby(['celebrities'])['No. of followers'].mean()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get statistics for each group (such as count, mean, etc) using pandas GroupBy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384532/get-statistics-for-each-group-such-as-count-mean-etc-using-pandas-groupby)

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer Joe. This is really useful with how to calculate the mean with the groupby function. However, I'm still not too sure how to incorporate the date filter with the groupby function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` to gather all rows by celebrity.

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(['celebrities'])
for name, group in df_grouped:
    print(group['Followers'].avg())
```

This will print for each celebrity the avg number of followers. You add your filter by dates if you would like too (`group[group['Date']>X]['Followers'].avg()`)

Comment: Hey Roim! Thank you for the solution. Any chance I'm able to do this in one line?

Comment: hmmm I think this ```df.groupby(['celebrities'])['Followers'].avg()``` will work but I didn't try myself

Answer (score 0):

If you want to incorporate the date filter, you need to filter your dataframe first:

```
    df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
    start_date = '2020/1/1'
    end_date = '2020/4/1'

    mask = (df["Date"] >= start_date) & (df["Date"] <= end_date)
    df = df.loc[mask]

    grouped = df.groupby("Celebrity").agg({"No. Followers": 
    "mean"}).reset_index()

    celebrities = np.unique(grouped["Celebrity"])

    dfs = {}

    for c in celebrities:
        dfs[c] = grouped[grouped["Celebrity"] == c]
```

You can then access your dataframes through a dictionary through the celebrity name as the key.

Hope that helps and please let me know if this answers your question.