# Percentage between a numerical and categorical variable

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have a dataset like below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"price" :[250,200,100,400,200,110], "segment": ["A","A","C","B","C","B"]})
```

I want to know how much percentage does each segment spent.
like

```
A = 35.71%
B = 40.47%
C = 23.82%
```

I have done through subsetting each segment and then doing percentage of each, but I want to do it in single line.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get statistics for each group (such as count, mean, etc) using pandas GroupBy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384532/get-statistics-for-each-group-such-as-count-mean-etc-using-pandas-groupby)

Comment: @BillHuangThis one only gives counts, I need percentage of the each segment spent value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try with `groupby` and applying `lambda` to each group. Something like:

1. first apply groupby 'segment'
2. then for each group take the segment sum multiplied by 100
3. and divide by total sum of df

As below:

```
df.groupby('segment')['price'].apply(lambda g: sum(g)*100.0/df.price.sum())
```

Result:

```
segment
A    35.714286
B    40.476190
C    23.809524
Name: price, dtype: float64
```