# column names setup after group by the data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

**My table is as bellowed**

```
datetime    source  Day area    Town    County  Country
0   2019-01-01 16:22:46 1273    Tuesday Brighton    Brighton    East Sussex England
1   2019-01-02 09:33:29 1823    Wednesday   Taunton Taunton Somerset    England
2   2019-01-02 09:44:46 1977    Wednesday   Pontefract  Pontefract  West Yorkshire  England
3   2019-01-02 10:01:42 1983    Wednesday   Isle of Wight   NaN NaN NaN
4   2019-01-02 12:03:13 1304    Wednesday   Dover   Dover   Kent    England
```

My codes are

```
counts_by_counties = call_by_counties.groupby(['County','Town']).count()
counts_by_counties.head()
```

My grouped result (Do the column name disappeared?)

```
                            datetime    source  Day    area  Country
County            Town                  
Aberdeenshire   Aberdeen            8       8      8    8       8
                Banchory            1       1      1    1       1
                Blackburn          18      18     18   18      18
                Ellon               6       6      6    6       6
                Fraserburgh         2       2      2    2       2
```

**I used this codes to rename the column, I am wondering if there is other efficent way to change the column name.**

```
# slicing of  the table 
counts_by_counties = counts_by_counties[['datetime',]]
# rename by datetime into Counts
counts_by_counties.rename(columns={'datetime': 'Counts'})
```

**Expected result**

```
                            Counts
County            Town  
Aberdeenshire   Aberdeen    8
                Banchory    1
                Blackburn   18
```

Comment: Please show an example of what you want the final output to look like.

Comment: I have edited the example, thank you for reminders.

Comment: maybe try `.size()` instead of `.count()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get statistics for each group (such as count, mean, etc) using pandas GroupBy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384532/get-statistics-for-each-group-such-as-count-mean-etc-using-pandas-groupby) See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32801170/3218693).

Comment: @chris thanks but I would not expect the values of first column repeat many times since there are few data in first column.

Comment: @BillHuang Thanks for this, I am looking for information about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call reset_index as below.
Replace

```
counts_by_counties = call_by_counties.groupby(['County','Town']).count()
```

with

```
counts_by_counties = call_by_counties.groupby(['County','Town']).count().reset_index()
```