# Separate count of values for dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

i recently looked at [Get statistics for each group (such as count, mean, etc) using pandas GroupBy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384532/get-statistics-for-each-group-such-as-count-mean-etc-using-pandas-groupby).  It does not address my issue.

Is there a way to get separate count of values for multiple df columns?

See my code:

```
Import pandas as pd
Import numpy as np
fle1 = r’k:\file1.xlsx’

df1 = pd.read_excel(fle1, sheet_name=”Sheet1”)
df2 = df1.select_dtypes(exclude=np.number)
col_names = df2.columns.values.tolist()
```

`col_names` contains `['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3']`

My dataframe looks like.

```
Column1     Column2          Column3  
Checking    Car              House  
Checking    Car              House  
Checking    Car              House  
House       Checking         Car 
House       Checking         Car
```

I'm Looking for output like:

```
Column1   Count  Column2    Count   Column3 Count
Checking    3    Car        3       House    3
House       2    Checking   2       Car      2
```

Not sure what next steps are, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.concat` and `groupby`:

```
(
    pd.concat([df[x].groupby(df[x]).size().to_frame('Count').reset_index() 
               for x in df.columns],1)
)

    Column1     Count   Column2     Count   Column3 Count
0   Checking    3       Car         3       Car     2
1   House       2       Checking    2       House   3
```