# Pandas. Leave only the most frequent rows in huge df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have df with 30 millions rows with form:

```
0;401
0;924
0;925
1;145
1;414
1;673
2;144
2;145
2;153
```

And I need to extract rows where the value in the first column is repeated multiple times (e.g. 100). I'm try rude method:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
state_last = None
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if row.loc['S1'] != state_last: # to skip iterations where I'm already estimate part of df
        state_last = row.loc['S1']
        temp = df.loc[df['S1']==row['S1']]
        if temp.shape[0] > 100:
            df1=df1.append(temp)
```

I also tried:

```
for i in range(19709): #max number in df
    temp = df.loc[df['S1']==i]
    if temp.shape[0] > 100:
            df1=df1.append(temp)
```

But these methods are too ineffective. Can this be done more quickly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @sammywemmy pls don't post solution as comment

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your columns as first_column and second_column

you can do

```
df = df.loc[df['first_column'].duplicated(keep=False), :]
```

you can read more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html)

EDIT:

You can do a group by on first_column and count the no of rows and then loc on count > 100

check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384532/get-statistics-for-each-group-such-as-count-mean-etc-using-pandas-groupby) from Pedro M Duarte

Comment: you don't need the `, :` ;)

Comment: This will allow me to delete rows that have no duplicates in the first column (I don't have any at all, I'm sure). I need to delete rows that have too few duplicates in the first column. For example, if the number rows with "1" in the first column is less than 100, then I do not need all the rows where the first column is "1".