# Struggling to insert a pie chart in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pie-chart

I have made a pie chart using an excel sheet but it is coming out incomplete. I am not sure of the reason. Here is the code:

```
import matlotplib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
Employee=pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Jon\\Desktop\\data science\\Employee.xlsx")
Employee

colors = ["#1f77b4", "#ff7f0e"]
group_by_departments=Employee.groupby("Department").count().reset_index()
sizes = group_by_departments['Gender']
labels = group_by_departments['Department']
plt.pie(sizes, labels=labels, colors = colors,autopct='%.2f %%')
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: A sample of `Employee` would help. What do you mean "it is coming out incomplete"?

Comment: It is missing a legend which should show 'Gender'. I cannot tell whether it is showing the number of employees in each department or just showing one gender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.size()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384532/get-statistics-for-each-group-such-as-count-mean-etc-using-pandas-groupby) to get the count for each group. You'll need to group by Department and Gender simultaneously to obtain the individual counts of all the subgroups.

Here is some example code:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N = 100
Employee = pd.DataFrame({'Gender': np.random.choice(['Male', 'Female'], N),
                         'Department': np.random.choice(['IT', 'Sales', 'HR', 'Finance'], N),
                         'Age': np.random.randint(20, 65, N),
                         'Salary': np.random.randint(20, 100, N) * 1000})
colors = ["turquoise", "tomato"]
group_by_departments_and_gender = Employee.groupby(["Department", "Gender"]).size().reset_index(name='Counts')
sizes = group_by_departments_and_gender['Counts']
labels = [f'{dept}\n {gender}' for dept, gender in group_by_departments_and_gender[['Department', 'Gender']].values]
plt.pie(sizes, labels=labels, colors=colors, autopct='%.2f %%')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: two-leveled pie chart]

PS: You could assign a color per gender via:

```py
colors = ["magenta" if gender=="Male" else "deepskyblue" for gender in group_by_departments_and_gender["Gender"]]
```

This especially helps in case one of the genders wouldn't be present in one of the departments.

Comment: done. I have accepted you answer