# I need to group a data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

[image]

I wish to group the data by director names and release_ year to see how many times each director's name appears yearly.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get statistics for each group (such as count, mean, etc) using pandas GroupBy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384532/get-statistics-for-each-group-such-as-count-mean-etc-using-pandas-groupby)

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. The code should be pasted into your question in a code block.

Answer (score 0):

Group the data by 'director_name' and 'release_year' and count the occurrences

```
grouped_data = df.groupby(['director_name', 'release_year']).size().reset_index(name='count')
```