# How to turn multiple rows of the same key with one differing column value in to one row consisting of the count of that variable column for each key

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that is structured like so:

```
pd.DataFrame(
    {'col1':['foo','foo','foo','foo','foo','foo'],'col2':['bar','bar','bar','bar','bar','bar'],'col3':['baz','baz','baz','baz','baz','baz'],'varying_column':['x','y','z','d','e','f']},index=['a','b','c','a','a','b']
    ).reset_index()


  my_key    col1    col2    col3    varying_column
0   a   foo bar baz x
1   b   foo bar baz y
2   c   foo bar baz z
3   a   foo bar baz d
4   a   foo bar baz e
5   b   foo bar baz f
```

Where each row has an index value and there is one column that varies. What I would like to do is just have one row for each index by creating a new column that is the count of `varying_column`, like so:

```
  my_key    col1    col2    col3    count_varying_column
0   a   foo bar baz 3
1   b   foo bar baz 2
2   c   foo bar baz 1
```

I assume this can be accomplished by doing some sort of `groupby` `index`, count `varying_column` and maybe `unstack`?

In my real data, the other columns also have varying values, but that is beside the point to this question, so I kept them all the same for simplicity.

Note: this is not just a simple group by aggregate as discussed in [this stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384532/get-statistics-for-each-group-such-as-count-mean-etc-using-pandas-groupby). Yes, I want the count for each group, but this question is different in that I want to drop duplicates for `varying_column` by key and replace it with a new column that has one row per key value and a new column `count_varying_column` that is a count of each keys `varying_column`.

Comment: `df.groupby(list(df.columns.difference(['varying_column'])), as_index=False).agg(count_varying_column=('varying_column', 'count'))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'col1':['foo','foo','foo','foo','foo','foo'],'col2':['bar','bar','bar','bar','bar','bar'],'col3':['baz','baz','baz','baz','baz','baz'],'varying_column':['x','y','z','d','e','f']},index=['a','b','c','a','a','b']
    ).reset_index()
df.groupby(['index','col1','col2','col3']).count().rename(columns={'varying_column':'count_varying_column'}).reset_index()


                      
  index col1 col2 col3  count_varying_column
0     a  foo  bar  baz                     3
1     b  foo  bar  baz                     2
2     c  foo  bar  baz                     1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `groupby` method in combination with `size` to count the occurrences, and then merge this result back with the original DataFrame to get the unique rows. After that, you can drop the duplicates based on the 'my_key' column.

Here's how you can do it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'my_key': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b'],
    'col1': ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo'],
    'col2': ['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar'],
    'col3': ['baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz'],
    'varying_column': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'd', 'e', 'f']
})
counts = df.groupby('my_key').size().reset_index(name='count_varying_column')
result = pd.merge(df.drop_duplicates(subset='my_key'), counts, on='my_key')
result = result.drop(columns=['varying_column'])

print(result)
```