# how to retrieve data from a data set based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas

i have this data

| Id | SpatialDimType | SpatialDim | TimeDim | Value | NumericValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32256659 | COUNTRY | ATU | 2022 | No data | NaN |
| 32256661 | COUNTRY | AND | 2022 | No data | NaN |
| 32256658 | COUNTRY | BHS | 2022 | No data | NAN |
| 32256642 | COUNTRY | AUS | 2022 | No data | NAN |

I want to retrieve a cont  for each data from spatialdim if the numercvalue= nan

for ex:

SpatialDim ///   cont ////   year

and       ///    36   ////   2022 \n
and       ///    21   ////   2002  \n
aut       ///    89   ////    2010
.
.
.
this is output should be

Comment: IIUC, you probably want `df[df['NumericValue'].isna()].groupby(['SpatialDim', 'TimeDim']).size()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [Get statistics for each group (such as count, mean, etc) using pandas GroupBy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384532/get-statistics-for-each-group-such-as-count-mean-etc-using-pandas-groupby)

- filter for rows where `NumericValue`is NaN
- group data by `SpatialDim` and `TimeDim` and find counts for unique pairs

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('./space.csv', sep=',')

df = df[df['NumericValue'].isna()].groupby(
    by=['SpatialDim', 'TimeDim']
).size().reset_index(name='count')

print(df)
```

suppose `./space.csv` is the following.

```
Id,SpatialDimType,SpatialDim,TimeDim,Value,NumericValue,Low,High
32256659,COUNTRY,AND,2022,No data,,,
32256659,COUNTRY,AND,2022,No data,,,
32256659,COUNTRY,AND,2023,No data,,,
32256661,COUNTRY,ATG,2022,No data,,,
32256664,COUNTRY,AUS,2001,No data,,,
32256664,COUNTRY,AUS,2001,No data,,,
32256664,COUNTRY,AUS,2001,No data,,,
32256664,COUNTRY,AUS,2004,No data,,,
32256664,COUNTRY,AUS,2004,No data,,,
32256665,COUNTRY,AUT,2004,No data,,,
```

this is the frequency/counts dataframe you get

```
  SpatialDim  TimeDim  count
0        AND     2022      2
1        AND     2023      1
2        ATG     2022      1
3        AUS     2001      3
4        AUS     2004      2
5        AUT     2004      1
```