# Reverting from multiindex to single index dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
                       NI
YEAR MONTH datetime        
2000 1     2000-01-01   NaN
           2000-01-02   NaN
           2000-01-03   NaN
           2000-01-04   NaN
           2000-01-05   NaN
```

In the dataframe above, I have a multilevel index consisting of the columns:

```
names=[u'YEAR', u'MONTH', u'datetime']
```

How do I revert to a dataframe with 'datetime' as index and 'YEAR' and 'MONTH' as normal columns?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

pass `level=[0,1]` to just reset those levels:

```
dist_df = dist_df.reset_index(level=[0,1])

In [28]:
df.reset_index(level=[0,1])

Out[28]:
            YEAR  MONTH  NI
datetime                     
2000-01-01  2000      1   NaN
2000-01-02  2000      1   NaN
2000-01-03  2000      1   NaN
2000-01-04  2000      1   NaN
2000-01-05  2000      1   NaN
```

you can pass the label names alternatively:

```
df.reset_index(level=['YEAR','MONTH'])
```

Comment: What if it's `dist_df.columns` are MultiIndex, not rows?

Comment: @DzmitryLazerka sorry I don't understand your comment, if you have a question please post a new question, answering questions in comments is not good form on SO

Comment: @DzmitryLazerka to flatten a multiindex (hierarchical) column / row index, you can use `.to_flat_index()`. See [this answer for code example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55757002/7515530)

Comment: Would this change the order of the array?

Answer (score 8):

Another simple way would be to set columns for dataframe

```
consolidated_data.columns=country_master
```

ref: https://riptutorial.com/pandas/example/18695/how-to-change-multiindex-columns-to-standard-columns