# Unexplained behavior with Pandas Split (group) + Apply + Rejoin (concat), but only when sorting

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, pandas-apply

I'm trying to calculate distances between a column and its lag (shift) for groups in a Pandas dataframe. The groups need to be sorted so that the shift is one timestep before. The standard way to do this is by `.groupby()` (aka Split), then `.apply()` with the distance function over each group, then rejoin with `.concat()`. This works fine, but only when I don't explicitly sort the grouped dataframe. when I sort the grouped dataframe, I get an error in the rejoining step.

Here's my example code, for which I was able to reproduce the unexpected behavior:

```
import pandas as pd

def dist_apply(group):

    # when commented out, this code will run to completion (!)
    group.sort_values(by='T',inplace=True)

    group['shift'] = group['Y'].shift()
    group['dist'] = group['Y'] - group['shift']
    return group

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame({'X': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'], 'T': [0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7], 'Y': [7, 1, 8, 3, 9, 5]}))
print(df)

# split
df_g = df.groupby(['X'])
# apply
df_g = df_g.apply(dist_apply)
print(df_g)

# rejoin
df = pd.concat([df,df_g],axis=1)
print(df)
```

When the code that sorts the grouped dataframe is commented out, then the code prints this, which is expected:

```
   X    T  Y
0  A  0.9  7
1  B  0.8  1
2  A  0.7  8
3  B  0.9  3
4  A  0.8  9
5  B  0.7  5

   X    T  Y  shift  dist
0  A  0.9  7    NaN   NaN
1  B  0.8  1    NaN   NaN
2  A  0.7  8    7.0   1.0
3  B  0.9  3    1.0   2.0
4  A  0.8  9    8.0   1.0
5  B  0.7  5    3.0   2.0

   X    T  Y  X    T  Y  shift  dist
0  A  0.9  7  A  0.9  7    NaN   NaN
1  B  0.8  1  B  0.8  1    NaN   NaN
2  A  0.7  8  A  0.7  8    7.0   1.0
3  B  0.9  3  B  0.9  3    1.0   2.0
4  A  0.8  9  A  0.8  9    8.0   1.0
5  B  0.7  5  B  0.7  5    3.0   2.0
```

With the sorting line, the Traceback looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    df = pd.concat([df,df_g],axis=1)
  File "/Users/me/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 229, in concat
    return op.get_result()
  File "/Users/me/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 420, in get_result
    indexers[ax] = obj_labels.reindex(new_labels)[1]
  File "/Users/me/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py", line 2236, in reindex
    target = MultiIndex.from_tuples(target)
  File "/Users/me/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py", line 396, in from_tuples
    arrays = list(lib.tuples_to_object_array(tuples).T)
  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 2287, in pandas._libs.lib.tuples_to_object_array
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Sorting but not running the concat prints me this for df_g:

```
     X    T  Y  shift  dist
X                          
A 2  A  0.7  8    NaN   NaN
  4  A  0.8  9    8.0   1.0
  0  A  0.9  7    9.0  -2.0
B 5  B  0.7  5    NaN   NaN
  1  B  0.8  1    5.0  -4.0
  3  B  0.9  3    1.0   2.0
```

which shows that it's grouped differently than the printing of df_g without the sorting (above), but it's not clear how the concat is breaking in this case.

---

*update*: I thought I had solved it by renaming the offending column ('X' in this case) and also using `.reset_index()` on the grouped dataframe before the merge.

```
df_g.columns = ['X_g','T','Y','shift','dist']
df = pd.concat([df,df_g.reset_index()],axis=1)
```

runs as expected, and prints this:

```
   X    T  Y  X  level_1 X_g    T  Y  shift  dist
0  A  0.9  7  A        2   A  0.7  8    NaN   NaN
1  B  0.8  1  A        4   A  0.8  9    8.0   1.0
2  A  0.7  8  A        0   A  0.9  7    9.0  -2.0
3  B  0.9  3  B        5   B  0.7  5    NaN   NaN
4  A  0.8  9  B        1   B  0.8  1    5.0  -4.0
5  B  0.7  5  B        3   B  0.9  3    1.0   2.0
```

But looking closely, this column shows that the merge is done incorrectly:

```
    1  B  0.8  1  A        4   A  0.8  9    8.0   1.0
```

---

I'm using Mac OSX with Python 3.7.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jan  7 2020, 22:05:27)

Pandas 0.24.2 + Numpy 1.17.3
and also tried upgrading to Pandas 0.25.3 and Numpy 1.17.5 with the same result.

Comment: The reason the `concat` is breaking is because `df` has a single index while `df_g` has a `MultiIndex`, so we can't combine them. The weird thing here is that `group[col].apply(pd.Series.shift)` doesn't return a `MultiIndex` while `group[col].apply(pd.Series.sort_values)` does. It isn't obvious to me from reading the docs why that is.

Comment: I'm not 100 % sure what your expected output is but I think you can fix it by `df_g.index = df_g.index.get_level_values(1)` before `pd.concat` but that fix seems a bit rough.

Comment: thanks @user3471881. this was a test case, so it's not so clear what I was trying to do. In my actual case, I have other columns in `df` that would need to be rejoined to `df_g`. My test case doesn't capture that.

Comment: thanks @user3471881. I added an answer that I "think" is working, but I have to check in my main code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59967503/2327328

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tentatively working.

Rename columns to avoid duplicate:

```
df_g.columns = ['X_g','T','Y','shift','dist']
```

[Reset index to single from multiindex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32938276/2327328):

```
df_g = df_g.reset_index(level=[0,1])
```

Simple merge, put `df_g` first if you want to keep the sorted-group order:

```
df = pd.merge(df_g,df)
```

gives me

```
   X  level_1 X_g    T  Y  shift  dist
0  A        2   A  0.7  8    NaN   NaN
1  A        4   A  0.8  9    8.0   1.0
2  A        0   A  0.9  7    9.0  -2.0
3  B        5   B  0.7  5    NaN   NaN
4  B        1   B  0.8  1    5.0  -4.0
5  B        3   B  0.9  3    1.0   2.0
```

Full code:

```
import pandas as pd

def dist_apply(group):

    group.sort_values(by='T',inplace=True)

    group['shift'] = group['Y'].shift()
    group['dist'] = group['Y'] - group['shift']
    return group

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame({'X': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'], 'T': [0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7], 'Y': [7, 1, 8, 3, 9, 5]}))
print(df)
df_g = df.groupby(['X'])

df_g = df_g.apply(dist_apply)

#print(df_g)

df_g.columns = ['X_g','T','Y','shift','dist']
df_g = df_g.reset_index(level=[0,1])

#print(df_g)
df = pd.merge(df_g,df)

print(df)
```