# After groupby, how to flatten column headers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to left join multiple pandas dataframes on a single `Id` column, but when I attempt the merge I get warning:

> KeyError: 'Id'.

I *think* it might be because my dataframes have offset columns resulting from a `groupby` statement, but I could very well be wrong. Either way I can't figure out how to "unstack" my dataframe column headers. None of the answers at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14507794/896802) seem to work.

My `groupby` code:

```
step1 = pd.DataFrame(step3.groupby(['Id', 'interestingtabsplittest2__grp'])['applications'].sum())
step1.sort('applications', ascending=False).head(3)
```

Returns:

[image: offset headers]

How to get those offset headers into the top level?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You're looking for [`.reset_index()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[2, 3], [5, 6]], pd.Index([1, 4], name="A"), columns=["B", "C"])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   B  C
A
1  2  3
4  5  6

In [13]: df.reset_index()
Out[13]:
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
```

---

Note: That you can avoid this step by using `as_index=False` when doing the groupby.

```
step1 = step3.groupby(['Id', 'interestingtabsplittest2__grp'], as_index=False)['applications'].sum()
```

Comment: If you implemented agg function at the end of the group. The column group couldn't be flatten by as_index. I found the answer from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50571897/7782929). Hope it helps for some people like me.

Comment: The solution that worked for me is `df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`  The **drop=True** was the critical part.

Answer (score 34):

The accepted answer doesn't work if you do multiple aggregation with `.agg()` or if you're grouping by multiple columns

You can instead drop the topmost level(s) and then reset the index.

```
df.droplevel(axis=1, level=0).reset_index()
```

Here, I have dropped only one level but you can pass an array instead as well:

```
df.droplevel(axis=1, level=[0,1]).reset_index()
```

Comment: best answer since it applies to multiple aggregation... thanks man