# Formatting Pandas dataframes to highlight column headers and remove blanks

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe

The dataframes I have created have the column headers on different rows with the columns I have included in the groupby statement being on a lower row than the others. How do I get all the column headers to be on the same row? I've tried the below 2 links and neither works.
[concise way of flattening multiindex columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50571793/concise-way-of-flattening-multiindex-columns/50571897#50571897)
[After groupby, how to flatten column headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004573/after-groupby-how-to-flatten-column-headers)

here is an example of a dataframe i created from another one using groupby

```
product_splits = dma_fees.groupby(['TRADEABLE_INSTR_NAME','SIG_CURRENCY_CODE']).sum()
product_splits = product_splits.drop('NUMBER_OF_LOTS',axis=1)
product_splits = product_splits.sort_values(by=['DMA_FEE_SUBTOTAL'],ascending=False)
product_splits = product_splits.round({'DMA_FEE_SUBTOTAL': 0}).astype(int)
```

and here is a picture of the dataframe it outputs and you can see dma_fee_subtotal is at a higher row / level than the groupby columns. How do I get these all on the same row?

[image]

Comment: Try `product_splits.reset_index()`

Comment: @AndrejKesely this works but then it adds a new index column to the left of the dataframe starting at 0. Is there a way to do this without the index column being added?