# How to visualize multi-index-ed data in orange?

Tags: python, pandas, orange

I am using `pandas` library in python to generate a multi-indexed data, i.e., the columns are multi-indexed. The indices are `category` and `source`. I save this data as `.csv` file. In the file, the first row is the `category` values and second row is corresponding `source` values, then the data follows. I use this file to visualize in Orange3 software. But it takes only the first row as the column name, how do I make it take column name as the combination of the two.

I am just trying to visualize the whole thing as a histogram, if possible.

1. Since, there are effectively 2 (`category` and `source`) + 1 (the row label) variables, 3d visualization would be best **or**
2. 1 (`category` and `source` combined variable) + 1 (the row label), 2d visualisation

`category    1    1    1    1    1    2    2 
 source      a    b    c    d    e    f    g 
 label
 l1          1    2    3    4    5    6    7 
 l2          4    5    6    7    8    9   10`

Comment: Could you provide the first few (4-5) lines of the csv file to clarify the structure?

Comment: i have edited the question to include a sample @astaric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://orange-visual-programming.readthedocs.io/loading-your-data/index.html), Orange does not support reading multi-indexed data.

In order to visualize the data, you will need to convert it to a normal tabular format (one column per feature) before exporting the data to csv.

One way to do it is the `DataFrame`'s `unstack` method:

```
df.unstack().to_csv("file.csv")
```

This will produce the file in the following format:

```
category    source    label
1           a         l1      1
1           a         l2      4
1           b         l1      2
...
```

This way, you can use category and source as separate variables in Orange.

.

To join category and source, you need to [flatten the hierarchical index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507794/python-pandas-how-to-flatten-a-hierarchical-index-in-columns) before exporting to csv:

```
df.columns = [' '.join(col).strip() for col in df.columns.values]
df.to_csv(file.csv)
```

This will produce the data in the following format:

```
label       1 a       1 b ...
l1          1         2
l2          4         5
```