# Rename result columns from Pandas aggregation ("FutureWarning: using a dict with renaming is deprecated")

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, rename

I'm trying to do some aggregations on a pandas data frame. Here is a sample code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"User": ["user1", "user2", "user2", "user3", "user2", "user1"],
                  "Amount": [10.0, 5.0, 8.0, 10.5, 7.5, 8.0]})

df.groupby(["User"]).agg({"Amount": {"Sum": "sum", "Count": "count"}})

Out[1]: 
      Amount      
         Sum Count
User              
user1   18.0     2
user2   20.5     3
user3   10.5     1
```

Which generates the following warning:

> FutureWarning: using a dict with renaming is deprecated and will be
>   removed in a future version   return super(DataFrameGroupBy,
>   self).aggregate(arg, *args, **kwargs)

How can I avoid this?

Comment: I'd love to know why this is being depreciated (I'm sure there is a good reason). Does anyone have a link to a discussion on it?

Comment: To focus on the keywords of the solution rather than just the existing warning, I retitled ***"rename result columns from aggregation"*** and tagged. Now people might even find this question :) ahead of (say) the not-so-canonical[Naming returned columns in Pandas aggregate function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078325/naming-returned-columns-in-pandas-aggregate-function)

Comment: Hopefully this will be addressed in https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18366

Comment: How would this work if I don't do a "groupby" but I'm doing "pivot" instead?

Comment: See pandas 0.25.0 [aggregation relabeling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html#groupby-aggregation-with-relabeling)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

## Use groupby `apply` and return a Series to rename columns

Use the groupby `apply` method to perform an aggregation that

- Renames the columns
- Allows for spaces in the names
- Allows you to order the returned columns in any way you choose
- Allows for interactions between columns
- Returns a single level index and NOT a MultiIndex

To do this:

- create a custom function that you pass to `apply`
- This custom function is passed each group as a DataFrame
- Return a Series
- The index of the Series will be the new columns

**Create fake data**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"User": ["user1", "user2", "user2", "user3", "user2", "user1", "user3"],
                  "Amount": [10.0, 5.0, 8.0, 10.5, 7.5, 8.0, 9],
                  'Score': [9, 1, 8, 7, 7, 6, 9]})
```

[image]

**create custom function that returns a Series**
The variable `x` inside of `my_agg` is a DataFrame

```
def my_agg(x):
    names = {
        'Amount mean': x['Amount'].mean(),
        'Amount std':  x['Amount'].std(),
        'Amount range': x['Amount'].max() - x['Amount'].min(),
        'Score Max':  x['Score'].max(),
        'Score Sum': x['Score'].sum(),
        'Amount Score Sum': (x['Amount'] * x['Score']).sum()}

    return pd.Series(names, index=['Amount range', 'Amount std', 'Amount mean',
                                   'Score Sum', 'Score Max', 'Amount Score Sum'])
```

**Pass this custom function to the groupby `apply` method**

```
df.groupby('User').apply(my_agg)
```

[image]

The big downside is that this function will be much slower than `agg` for the [cythonized aggregations](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#cython-optimized-aggregation-functions)

## Using a dictionary with groupby `agg` method

Using a dictionary of dictionaries was removed because of its complexity and somewhat ambiguous nature. There is an [ongoing discussion](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18366#issuecomment-349090402) on how to improve this functionality in the future on github Here, you can directly access the aggregating column after the groupby call. Simply pass a list of all the aggregating functions you wish to apply.

```
df.groupby('User')['Amount'].agg(['sum', 'count'])
```

Output

```
       sum  count
User              
user1  18.0      2
user2  20.5      3
user3  10.5      1
```

It is still possible to use a dictionary to explicitly denote different aggregations for different columns, like here if there was another numeric column named `Other`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"User": ["user1", "user2", "user2", "user3", "user2", "user1"],
              "Amount": [10.0, 5.0, 8.0, 10.5, 7.5, 8.0],
              'Other': [1,2,3,4,5,6]})

df.groupby('User').agg({'Amount' : ['sum', 'count'], 'Other':['max', 'std']})
```

Output

```
      Amount       Other          
         sum count   max       std
User                              
user1   18.0     2     6  3.535534
user2   20.5     3     5  1.527525
user3   10.5     1     4       NaN
```

Comment: But suppose you do want the renaming aspect as well, to have different column names than the default after aggregation. Is there some syntax to still get this functionality?

Comment: Had same question about naming, since I am using the same col twice (one  min and one max) and need a way to refer to them uniquely when I put results back in objects.

Comment: If you want to rename the columns you will have to do it manually. Either use a list to replace all of them `df.columns = ['your', 'new', 'col', 'names']` or use the `rename` method which will be a bit difficult since you have this results in a MultiIndex.

Comment: @ErnestScribbler I have updated this answer to show a fairly simple way of performing an aggregation, renaming and returning a single-level index.

Comment: How would the apply method work with 'first' and 'last'?

Comment: why don't you need to pass an argument to my_agg when you call it?

Comment: @Snow .agg() can take a function that as parameter.

Comment: I entered wrong column and got the same deprecated warning `df.groupby('User')['Amount'].agg({'Amount' : ['sum', 'count'], 'Other':['max', 'std']})`

Answer (score 21):

## Update for Pandas 0.25+  [Aggregation relabeling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html#groupby-aggregation-with-relabeling)

```
import pandas as pd

print(pd.__version__)
#0.25.0

df = pd.DataFrame({"User": ["user1", "user2", "user2", "user3", "user2", "user1"],
                  "Amount": [10.0, 5.0, 8.0, 10.5, 7.5, 8.0]})

df.groupby("User")['Amount'].agg(Sum='sum', Count='count')
```

Output:

```
        Sum  Count
User              
user1  18.0      2
user2  20.5      3
user3  10.5      1
```

Comment: But in this case, the names `Sum` and `Count` have to be valid Python names. You couldn't replace `Sum` with `Sum of foos`. :(

Comment: @Dror you can use this format  `df.groupby('User').agg(**{'sum of foos':pd.NamedAgg('Amount','sum'),
                          'count of foos':pd.NamedAgg('Amount','count')})`

Comment: Indeed, this works, but it unfortunately, it is so much more cumbersome when compared to the dictionary based aggregation API.

Comment: @Dror You don't need to include the `pd.NamedAgg` part which shortens the amount of code. This is now my preferred way of doing this. Pass in a dictionary with `**` in front of it.

Answer (score 17):

If you replace the internal dictionary with a list of tuples it gets rid of the warning message

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"User": ["user1", "user2", "user2", "user3", "user2", "user1"],
                  "Amount": [10.0, 5.0, 8.0, 10.5, 7.5, 8.0]})

df.groupby(["User"]).agg({"Amount": [("Sum", "sum"), ("Count", "count")]})
```

Comment: Do you know if this will also (presumably) work in the future release or is  also just to workaround the warning message?

Comment: @Peanut, I do not know.  But if the warning message is not there, then presumably (as you say) it will continue to be supported.

Comment: This is an undocumented and accidental feature and I would highly suggest no one using this syntax as it may not work in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the information @TedPetrou.  And thanks for the link to the discussion in your answer.  It sounds like a difficult question to find the right syntax.

Comment: Is this indeed unstable behavior as @TedPetrou mentioned?

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me, Pandas version **1.2.4**

For each column we add a list which consists of tuples:

```
df.groupby('column to group by').agg(
{'column name': [('new column name', 'function to apply')]})
```

Example

```
# Create DataFrame
df=pd.DataFrame(data={'id':[1,1,2,3],'col1': [1,2,1,5], 'col2':[5,8,6,4]})

# Apply grouping 
grouped = df.groupby('id').agg({
                             'col1': [('name1', 'sum')], 
                             'col2': [('name2_mean', 'sum'), ('name2_custom_std', lambda x: np.std(x))]})

# Drop multi-index for columns and reset index
grouped.columns = grouped.columns.droplevel()
grouped.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Result:

|  | id | name1 | name2_mean | name2_custom_std |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 3 | 13 | 1.5 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 6 | 0.0 |
| 2 | 3 | 5 | 4 | 0.0 |

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did:

Create a fake dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"User": ["user1", "user2", "user2", "user3", "user2", "user1", "user3"],
                  "Amount": [10.0, 5.0, 8.0, 10.5, 7.5, 8.0, 9],
                  'Score': [9, 1, 8, 7, 7, 6, 9]})
df
```

O/P:

```
    Amount  Score   User
0   10.0    9   user1
1   5.0 1   user2
2   8.0 8   user2
3   10.5    7   user3
4   7.5 7   user2
5   8.0 6   user1
6   9.0 9   user3
```

I first made the User the index, and then a groupby:

```
ans = df.set_index('User').groupby(level=0)['Amount'].agg([('Sum','sum'),('Count','count')])
ans
```

Solution:

```
    Sum Count
User        
user1   18.0    2
user2   20.5    3
user3   19.5    2
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the inner dictionaries with a list of correctly named functions.

To rename the function I'm using this utility function:

```py
def aliased_aggr(aggr, name):
    if isinstance(aggr,str):
        def f(data):
            return data.agg(aggr)
    else:
        def f(data):
            return aggr(data)
    f.__name__ = name
    return f
```

The group-by statement then becomes:

```py
df.groupby(["User"]).agg({"Amount": [ 
    aliased_aggr("sum","Sum"),
    aliased_aggr("count","Count")
]
```

If you have bigger, reusable aggregation specs, you can convert them with

```py
def convert_aggr_spec(aggr_spec):
    return {
        col : [ 
            aliased_aggr(aggr,alias) for alias, aggr in aggr_map.items() 
        ]  
        for col, aggr_map in aggr_spec.items() 
    }
```

So you can say

```py
df.groupby(["User"]).agg(convert_aggr_spec({"Amount": {"Sum": "sum", "Count": "count"}}))
```

See also https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18366#issuecomment-476597674

Comment: Ok, I got carried away with this: this is essentially recreating what already is in pandas, as illustrated in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50697003/1419571)  proposed by @jacob-stevenson

Comment: ... but there are other circumstances where it is useful to carry the aliases in the aggregation spec items themselves. So i leave the answer as is.