# How to groupby() aggregate on multiple columns and rename the multi-index in Pandas 0.21+?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, sklearn-pandas

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
                    'B': range(5),
                    'C': range(5)})

df1 = df.groupby('A').B.agg({'B': ['count','nunique'],'C': ['sum','median']})
df1.columns = ["_".join(x) for x in df1.columns.ravel()]
```

**df1 Output**

```
   B_count  B_nunique  C_sum  C_median
A                                     
1        3          3      3       1.0
2        2          2      7       3.5
```

**Warning**

```
__main__:1: FutureWarning: using a dict on a Series for aggregation
is deprecated and will be removed in a future version
```

This was the recommended way to groupby and rename till Pandas 0.20. What is the elegant way to achieve the same df1 output without this warning?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635626/pandas-aggregation-warning-futurewarning-using-a-dict-with-renaming-is-depreca

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @Wen stated in question comments, remove the '.B' before agg, and your dictionary inside of agg is proper.  Next, you can use `map` and `join` to flatten that multiindex columns.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
                    'B': range(5),
                    'C': range(5)})

df1 = df.groupby('A').agg({'B': ['count','nunique'],'C': ['sum','median']})
df1.columns = df1.columns.map('_'.join)
```

Output:

```
   B_count  B_nunique  C_sum  C_median
A                                     
1        3          3      3       1.0
2        2          2      7       3.5
```