# pandas: how to group by multiple columns and perform different aggregations on multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Lets say I have a table that look like this:

```
Company      Region     Date           Count         Amount
AAA          XXY        3-4-2018       766           8000
AAA          XXY        3-14-2018      766           8600
AAA          XXY        3-24-2018      766           2030
BBB          XYY        2-4-2018        66           3400
BBB          XYY        3-18-2018       66           8370
BBB          XYY        4-6-2018        66           1380
```

I want to get rid of the Date column, then **aggregate by Company AND region** to ***find the average of Count and sum of Amount***.

Expected output:

```
Company      Region     Count         Amount
AAA          XXY        766           18630
BBB          XYY        66            13150
```

I looked into this post here, and many other posts online, but seems like they are only performing one kind of aggregation action (for example, I can aggregate by multiple columns but can only produce one column output as sum OR count, NOT sum AND count)

[Rename result columns from Pandas aggregation ("FutureWarning: using a dict with renaming is deprecated")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635626/rename-result-columns-from-pandas-aggregation-futurewarning-using-a-dict-with/44635693#44635693)

Can someone help?

What I did:

I followed this post here:

https://www.shanelynn.ie/summarising-aggregation-and-grouping-data-in-python-pandas/

however, when i try to use the method presented in this article (toward the end of the article), by using dictionary:

```
aggregation = {
    'Count': {
        'Total Count': 'mean'
    },
    'Amount': {
        'Total Amount': 'sum'
    }
}
```

I would get this warning:

```
FutureWarning: using a dict with renaming is deprecated and will be removed in a future version
  return super(DataFrameGroupBy, self).aggregate(arg, *args, **kwargs)
```

I know it works now but i want to make sure my script works later too. How can I update my code to be compatible in the future?

Comment: please post your expected output as well.

Comment: @HaleemurAli added!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Need aggregate by single non nested dictionary and then `rename` columns:

```
aggregation = {'Count':  'mean', 'Amount': 'sum'}
cols_d = {'Count': 'Total Count', 'Amount': 'Total Amount'}

df = df.groupby(['Company','Region'], as_index=False).agg(aggregation).rename(columns=cols_d)
print (df)
  Company Region  Total Count  Total Amount
0     AAA    XXY          766         18630
1     BBB    XYY           66         13150
```

Another solution with [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) instead `rename`:

```
aggregation = {'Count':  'mean', 'Amount': 'sum'}
df = df.groupby(['Company','Region']).agg(aggregation).add_prefix('Total ').reset_index()
print (df)
  Company Region  Total Count  Total Amount
0     AAA    XXY          766         18630
1     BBB    XYY           66         13150
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby(['Region', 'Company']).agg({'Count': 'mean', 'Amount': 'sum'}).reset_index()
```

outputs:

```
  Region Company  Count  Amount
0    XXY     AAA    766   18630
1    XYY     BBB     66   13150
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.groupby(["Company","Region"]).agg({"Count":'mean',"Amount":'sum'})
```