# creating aggregation with lambda in loop

Tags: python

Let's say I have a dataframe like this:

```
 v1 v2
 a  1
 a  1
 b  1
 b  2
```

I would like to groupby on v1 and make the count of each possible value in v2.
So the result would be something like:

```
    v2    
     1  2
 v1
  a  2  0 
  b  1  1
```

I can do something like this

```
df.groupby("v1")\
.agg(
    {
    "v2": {
             "0": lambda x: sum(x==0),
             "1": lambda x: sum(x==1)
           }
    }
}
```

But it's not really nice if the number of values is hight, or change!
I've seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635626/rename-result-columns-from-pandas-aggregation-futurewarning-using-a-dict-with) but couldn't make it working with my example.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient method is `crosstab`:

`pd.crosstab(df['v1'], columns = df['v2'])`

Result

```
v2  1  2
v1
a   2  0
b   1  1
```

[Pandas `crosstab` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.crosstab.html).

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong,
You don't need agg function to obtain this result
You just need to groupby v1 and v2. Unstack it.

```
v1 = 'a a b b'.split()
v2 = '1 1 1 2'.split()
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'v1': v1,
                   'v2': v2})

print(df)
g = df.groupby(['v1', 'v2'])
print(g.size().unstack())
```

This will return

```
v2    1    2
v1          
a   2.0  NaN
b   1.0  1.0
```

To fill the NaN.

```
print(g.size().unstack().fillna(0))
v2    1    2
v1          
a   2.0  0.0
b   1.0  1.0
```