# How to access a column within a column using pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

All,

I have a dataframe that looks like this: `df[['date','PRICE']]`

```
df>>

date                   Price
                 PX_FIRST     PX_LAST

2018-03-05        1.710       -0.511
2018-03-06        1.725       -0.513
2018-03-07        1.745       -0.511
2018-03-08        1.750       -0.512
```

how can I get a dataframe similar to this? in other words how can I access PX_FIRST and PX_LAST. When I do `df[['date','PRICE']]`  it dont manage to access individual columns.

```
  date           PX_FIRST     PX_LAST

2018-03-05        1.710       -0.511
2018-03-06        1.725       -0.513
2018-03-07        1.745       -0.511
2018-03-08        1.750       -0.512
```

Comment: Do you want to flatten the multiindex columns permanently, or just have a nicer view?

Comment: @jpp  I want to flatten the multi index columns please. still trying the solution proposed by jezrael

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Pandas - How to flatten a hierarchical index in columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507794/python-pandas-how-to-flatten-a-hierarchical-index-in-columns)

Comment: @SBad - Give me as sec, I try explain for possible problem with it. I edit answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need select columns under `Price` value of first level:

```
df = df['Price']
```

Or use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
df = df.xs('Price', axis=1)
print (df)
            PX_FIRST  PX_LAST
Date                         
2018-03-05     1.710   -0.511
2018-03-06     1.725   -0.513
2018-03-07     1.745   -0.511
2018-03-08     1.750   -0.512
```

---

If need remove top level of `MultiIndex`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
```

But be carefull if more columns with different first level (`Price`, `Price1`) and same values in second level:

```
#create sample data
df = pd.concat([df['Price'], df['Price'] * 0.4], keys=('Price','Price1'), axis=1)
print (df)
              Price           Price1        
           PX_FIRST PX_LAST PX_FIRST PX_LAST
Date                                        
2018-03-05    1.710  -0.511    0.684 -0.2044
2018-03-06    1.725  -0.513    0.690 -0.2052
2018-03-07    1.745  -0.511    0.698 -0.2044
2018-03-08    1.750  -0.512    0.700 -0.2048
```

Remove first level:

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
print (df)
            PX_FIRST  PX_LAST  PX_FIRST  PX_LAST
Date                                            
2018-03-05     1.710   -0.511     0.684  -0.2044
2018-03-06     1.725   -0.513     0.690  -0.2052
2018-03-07     1.745   -0.511     0.698  -0.2044
2018-03-08     1.750   -0.512     0.700  -0.2048
```

If select column `PX_FIRST` it return `DataFrame`, because duplicated columns names:

```
print (df['PX_FIRST'])
            PX_FIRST  PX_FIRST
Date                          
2018-03-05     1.710     0.684
2018-03-06     1.725     0.690
2018-03-07     1.745     0.698
2018-03-08     1.750     0.700
```

If need select by both levels, use tuples:

```
print (df[('Price', 'PX_FIRST')])
Date
2018-03-05    1.710
2018-03-06    1.725
2018-03-07    1.745
2018-03-08    1.750
Name: (Price, PX_FIRST), dtype: float64
```

Comment: Nice one sir, learn new thing , Never thought xs. can be used like this

Comment: @jezrael  please see my answer below

Comment: @SBad - I cannot see it, is posted?

Answer (score 3):

IIUC multiple index

```
df.loc[:,pd.IndexSlice['Price']]
Out[1108]: 
            PX_FIRST  PX_LAST
Date                         
2018-03-05     1.710   -0.511
2018-03-06     1.725   -0.513
2018-03-07     1.745   -0.511
2018-03-08     1.750   -0.512
```

Answer (score 0):

@jezrael You are exactly right when I drop one level I end up with a duplicate column name and it is hard to distinguish columns unless I rename them?

The other challenge in your example below

```
            PX_FIRST  PX_FIRST
Date                          
2018-03-05     1.710     0.684
2018-03-06     1.725     0.690
2018-03-07     1.745     0.698
2018-03-08     1.750     0.700
```

is that column "Date", "PX_FIRST" and "PX_FIRST" are in different levels so I call df[['Date','PX_FIRST','PX_FIRST']] i get an error `"...not in index"`

Ideally, i d be looking to get

```
 Date          PX_FIRST  PX_LAST                              
2018-03-05     1.710     0.684
2018-03-06     1.725     0.690
2018-03-07     1.745     0.698
2018-03-08     1.750     0.700
```

All column names are on a similar level and have different names

Thanks

Comment: You need `df = df.reset_index()`, then is possible use `df[['Date','PX_FIRST','PX_FIRST']]`

Comment: because first column is index and `Date` is index name, not column name

Comment: @jezrael  Thanks a lot. because the structure of  my data is unusual. I had to drop 2 levels and reindex the date to finally get the desired results.  Thank you again