# Create named cells in multiple sheets with same name openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am creating excel file with multiple sheets. In every sheet i need same define name with group of rows and columns.we can create it manually but through program how to achieve this.

Below is the code:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file.xlsx)
shee1 = wb['sheet1']
shee2 = wb['sheet1']
wb.create_named_range('sales', shee1 , '$B$11:$B$35')
wb.create_named_range('sales', shee2 , '$B$11:$B$35')
```

following is the error i am getting

> File
>   "C:\Users\728355\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py",
>   line 319, in create_named_range
>       self.defined_names.append(defn)   File "C:\Users\728355\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\defined_name.py",
>   line 201, in append
>       raise ValueError("""DefinedName with the same name and scope already exists""") ValueError: DefinedName with the same name and
>   scope already exists

Comment: `shee2 = wb['sheet1']`... typo? Should it be `shee2 = wb['sheet2']`?

Comment: What part of the exception don't you understand?

Answer (score 1):

I think the named ranges are global to the workbook, not local to each sheet. Which is hinted at by the error message you're getting:

> DefinedName with the same name and scope already exists

So you'd have to give those different names

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file.xlsx)
sheet1 = wb['sheet1']
sheet2 = wb['sheet2']
wb.create_named_range('sales1', sheet1 , '$B$11:$B$35')
wb.create_named_range('sales2', sheet2 , '$B$11:$B$35')
```

or a more DRY solution:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file.xlsx)
sheets = []
for sheet_no in range(1,3):
    sheets[sheet_no] = wb[f'sheet{sheet_no}'] # note pre python 3.6 you should change f'sheet{sheet_no}' to 'sheet{}'.format(sheet_no)
    wb.create_named_range(f'sales{sheet_no}', sheets[sheet_no], '$B$11:$B$35')
```

Comment: Probably make sense to make the scope an explicit parameter.

Comment: @CharlieClark The scope? You mean the range: `'$B$11:$B$35'`? Or do you mean the `3` in `range(1,3)`? Or are you saying it's possible to define the scope of the named range - because if that's the case then maybe you should add an answer with how to do that because it sounds like a good idea

Comment: Sorry, `localSheetId` (index of the worksheet in the workbook). It used to be called `scope`.