# Using openpyxl create a names range in a spreadsheet

Tags: python, openpyxl

I've had a look around and can see how using `openpyxl` to use named ranges that are in a spreadsheet tab.  However I haven't been able to see if you can actually create a named range in a spreadsheet tab via `openpyxl`...

Is this possible? What could I try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create named cells in multiple sheets with same name openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52719346/create-named-cells-in-multiple-sheets-with-same-name-openpyxl)

Comment: Thanks buran, this gives me something to work with

Comment: I am not sure it's mentioned in the docs, but you can look at `Workbook.create_named_range()` method source code - https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/src/2e6579803a43baa49a670731d3b7722696c63cca/openpyxl/workbook/workbook.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default