# How to add conditions to columns at grouped by pivot table Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, pandas-groupby

I've used group by and pivot table from pandas package in order to create the following table:

Input:

```
q4 = q1[['category','Month']].groupby(['category','Month']).Month.agg({'Count':'count'}).reset_index()
q4 = pd.DataFrame(q4.pivot(index='category',columns='Month').reset_index())
```

then the output :

```
category                            Count
Month                       6       7       8
0   adult-classes           29.0    109.0   162.0
1   air-pollution           27.0    43.0    13.0
2   babies-and-toddlers     4.0     51.0    2.0
3   bicycle                 210.0   96.0    23.0
4   building                NaN     17.0    NaN
5   buildings-maintenance   23.0    12.0    NaN
6   catering                1351.0  4881.0  1040.0
7   childcare               9.0     NaN     NaN
8   city-planning           105.0   81.0    23.0
9   city-services           2461.0  2130.0  1204.0
10  city-taxes              1.0     4.0     42.0
```

I'm trying to add a condition to the months,
the problem I'm having is that after pivoting I can't access the columns

how can I show only the rows where 6<7<8?

Comment: There is no question here. Please format your text and write something about what you are attempting to do.

Comment: fixed. thanks for the comment

Comment: All right, that's better :-) Okay, so your output is what you are starting to work with. And you would like to filter out rows wrt the above condition. One more question: how do you want to handle rows where one of `6`, `7` or `8` is `NaN`?

Comment: NaN will be as 0

Answer (score 1):

To flatten your multi-index, you can use renaming of your columns (check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507794/python-pandas-how-to-flatten-a-hierarchical-index-in-columns)).

```py
q4.columns = [''.join([str(c) for c in col]).strip() for col in q4.columns.values]
```

To remove `NaN`s:

```py
q4.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

To select according to your constraint:

```py
result = q4[(q4['Count6'] < q['Count7']) & (q4['Count7'] < q4['Count8'])]
```

Comment: your doubt is exactly the problem I'm having.
I can't access these columns after pivoting

Comment: Hey, found something. Check my edited answer. Now it should be working from A to Z :).

Comment: the first multi-index gives the following error:
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, int found

removing NaN seems to work.

the last one will no compile

Comment: that's because in the data I was testing, all columns were `str`, but in your there were `int`. check my again edited answer ;-)

Comment: you've done something good now it's like that

 "c a t e g o r y C o u n t 6 C o u n t 7 C o u n t 8
0 adult-classes 29.0 109.0 162.0
1 air-pollution 27.0 43.0 13.0
2 babies-and-toddlers 4.0 51.0 2.0

but still the last one don't work

Comment: q4.columns = [''.join([str(c) for c in col]).strip() for col in q4.columns.values]
q4.fillna(0, inplace=True)
results = q4[(q4['Count6'] < q4['Count7']) & (q4['Count7'] < q4['Count8'])]
results.rename(index=str, columns={"Count6": "June", "Count7": "July","Count8": "August" })

                           that's the final code after minor fix!!! thanks a lot!!!!! <3

Comment: happy to hear you did it :)