# Transforming columns with multiple indexes/headers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two headers like this:

[image: Image1]

I want to transform it to have one header. Desired output:

[image: Image2]

I have followed some solutions on stack-overflow about multi-indexing and multi-headers, but I am not able to achieve the result I want. Can anybody help me solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `df.columns = df.columns.map(''.join)`, check [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14507794/2901002)

Comment: It is giving me this error: `can only join an iterable`