# How to work with columns after using to_flat_index?

Tags: python, pandas

I observed some strange behaviour of the column names when using to_flat_index() function.

Starting with a MultiIndex dataframe

```
a=[0,.25, .5, .75]
b=[1, 2, 3, 4]
c=[5, 6, 7, 8]
d=[1, 2, 3, 5]
df=pd.DataFrame(data={('a','a'):a, ('b', 'b'):b, ('c', 'c'):c, ('d', 'd'):d})
```

Produces this dataframe

```
      a  b  c  d
      a  b  c  d
0  0.00  1  5  1
1  0.25  2  6  2
2  0.50  3  7  3
3  0.75  4  8  5
```

Use the .to_flat_index to flatten the index

```
df.columns = df.columns.to_flat_index()
```

Produces the following dataframe

```
    (a, a)  (b, b)  (c, c)  (d, d)
0   0.00    1   5   1
1   0.25    2   6   2
2   0.50    3   7   3
3   0.75    4   8   5
```

If I try to select a column using df['(a, a)'] method I get a KeyError message. If I try to clean up the column name using df.columns = df.columns.str.lower().str.rstrip() (or any other .str method) I get nan instead of column names

```
NaN NaN NaN NaN
0   0.00    1   5   1
1   0.25    2   6   2
2   0.50    3   7   3
3   0.75    4   8   5
```

What am I doing wrong. How can I select the column after using to_flat_index()?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507794/pandas-how-to-flatten-a-hierarchical-index-in-columns This thread might be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to select one column you have to do it with a tuple:

```
df[('a', 'a')]
```

If you only want one level column with the first element of the tuple as the name this should be enough:

```
df.columns = df.columns.to_flat_index().map(lambda x: x[0])
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to get a real flat index of multiindex columns? I basically need column names like 'a_a', 'b_b', etc.

Comment: Yes, with  `df.columns.to_flat_index().map(lambda x: '_'.join(x))`

Answer (score 0):

With `to_flat_index()` you are converting the `columns` into a list of tuple, where elements of tuples are the level values of multinindex.

For the given multindex after flattening, the new columns are `[('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('c', 'c'), ('d', 'd')]`

So when you are applying string method's on the values of columns e.g. `('a', 'a')` will return `None` which becomes `NaN`.

If you're trying to extract one specific level of values you can do so by,

`df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(0) # level index`

Assuming a complicated operation on the multiple levels of data frame

```py
join_str_with_char = lambda mi_cols, jstr: jstr.join([_.strip() for _ in mi_cols])

df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: join_str_with_char(x,'_'))
```