# Changing 2 different rows as a single row without pivoting in Pandas (when dataframe is not Mulitindex)

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have this table that shows edit, upload and move rights for a page and also along with each right 3 other properties like Cascade, Expiry and Permissions.
[image]

Now I want to change multiple entries into a single row such that it has columns like Edit_Permissions, Move_Permissions, Upload_Permissions, Edit_Cascade, Move_Cascade, Upload_Cascade, Edit_Expiry, Move_Expiry, Upload_Expiry (I want a flattened column classification) but when I used pivot feature of Pandas, the new dataframe shows multiple hierarchical column classification)
[image]

Is there any way I can get columns in a flattened manner, just like this:
[image]

Please note the resultant dataframe is not a Multi index column dataframe, I checked using this piece of code:
[image]

Comment: Please see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507794/pandas-how-to-flatten-a-hierarchical-index-in-columns

Comment: @annicheez the post you referred suggest solution for Multi index column dataframe, my dataframe is not multi-index (it seems hierarchical due to pivoting), I have edited the question