# Pandas Pivot Table MultiIndex Columns to Single Level

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like as follows:

```
df = 
    COLUMN_NAME  YEAR1  YEAR2   VALUE
0   Column1       2013   2014   0.042835
1   Column1       2014   2015   0.033600
2   Column2       2013   2014   0.004406
3   Column2       2014   2015   0.016900
...
```

Where for each COLUMN_NAME, YEAR1 and YEAR2, a VALUE is calculated. I want to group the dataframe such that is it unique on COLUMN_NAME, where the columns look like the following:

```
df_desired = 
    COLUMN_NAME  Value_from_2013_2014   Value_from_2014_2015 ...
0   Column1      0.042835                  0.033600
1   Column2      0.004406                  0.016900
...
```

I can achieve sort of what I want with the code below, but it creates a MultiIndex columns, how can I achieve this? Thanks for the help.

```
pd.pivot_table(df, 'VALUE', 'COLUMN_NAME', ['YEAR1', 'YEAR2'])

YEAR1         2013      2014
YEAR2         2014      2015
COLUMN_NAME     
Column1       0.042835  0.0336
Column2       0.004406  0.0169
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas - How to flatten a hierarchical index in columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507794/pandas-how-to-flatten-a-hierarchical-index-in-columns)

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten the multiindex columns using `to_flat_index`, then `map` to `str` and add your prefix:

```
s.columns = ["Value_from_"+"_".join(map(str, i)) for i in s.columns.to_flat_index()]

print (s)

             Value_from_2013_2014  Value_from_2014_2015
COLUMN_NAME                                            
Column1                  0.042835                0.0336
Column2                  0.004406                0.0169
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df_agg = pd.pivot_table(df, 'VALUE', 'COLUMN_NAME', ['YEAR1', 'YEAR2'])
df_agg.columns = ['Value_from_' + str(df_agg.columns[i][0]) + '_' + str(df_agg.columns[i][1]) for i in range(len(df_agg.columns))]
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27632709)

Comment: @RohanSingh: While this would certainly benefit from additional explanation, it's worth noting that answers needn't be complete—at least assuming there isn't yet an accepted answer ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)).

Answer (score -1):

If I understanding correctly, you are getting the desired values, but not the desired labels. If so, you can change the column names with `df_desired.columns = ['Value_from_2013_2014', 'Value_from_2014_2015']`