# Rename multiline header column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.6

How do i rename a column in pandas created from a multirow header?

I've attempted

```py
df = pd.read_excel(filepath,header=[0,1])
df.rename(
    columns={"col name, line 2":"New_Column_name"}
          ,inplace=True)

# Also attempted

df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]: 'New_Column_name'},inplace=True)
```

Neither of those result in a renamed column, old name persists

Answer (score 0):

Loading data this way created a multindex so python couldn't find the object using index, for named items this worked for me.

```py
df.rename(
    columns={"col name":"New_Column_name"}
          ,inplace=True)
```

Flattening the hierachical index as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507794/pandas-how-to-flatten-a-hierarchical-index-in-columns) answer and then renaming was the better solution